# How to get HTML5 form input default value

Tags: php, angularjs

It's working fine when I type something in the input field but I couldn't get the input value from the front end when the input has the default value.

I use `Input::get()` to cacth the value

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="name" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your name" ng-model="name"/>
```

I use AngularJs to bind the value from the database then pass it to `ng-model` for the display default value on the input. However, I couldn't get the default value

This is my submit button

```
<input type="submit" name="student" ng-model="student" ng-click="submit()" novalidate value="Sync Sale" class="btn btn-primary" ng-</input>
```

Comment: In your second code block there is clearly missing something, class-attribute and input-tag gets not closed.

Answer (score 0):

If u want get input value from input tag use AngularJS directive `ng-model`.

The `ng-model` directive binds the value of HTML controls (input, select, textarea) to application data.

for eg:-

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  Name: <input ng-model="name">
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = "John Doe";
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to define the input value of an input.
You should check the **ng-value** directive of Angular.

Here's an example from the angular doc :

```
<label ng-repeat="name in names" for="{{name}}">
   {{name}}
   <input type="radio"
          ng-model="my.favorite"
          ng-value="name"
          id="{{name}}"
          name="favorite">
 </label>
```

You can try it out whith this plunker if you want to :
https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview